# android emulator - What is the format of virtualscene\posters=@Variant

Tags: android, image, shell, testing, emulation

I m trying to change the images of photo from command line, to automate a integrated tests of an apk. But I dont know what format the image becames when put manualy from the android emulator ide.

When I add a Image manually from here
[Like this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eezT.png)

In file .android/avd//AVD.conf
Have this line `virtualscene\posters=@Variant` and after a code of the image like

```
\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\b\0w\0\x61\0l\0l\0\0\0\n\0\0\0\x90\0\x43\0:\0/\0P\0r\0o\0g\0r\0\x61\0m\0 \0\x46\0i\0l\0\x65\0s\0/\0\x41\0n\0\x64\0r\0o\0i\0\x64\0/\0\x41\0n\0\x64\0r\0o\0i\0\x64\0 \0S\0t\0u\0\x64\0i\0o\0\x31\0/\0j\0r\0\x65\0/\0j\0r\0\x65\0/\0\x62\0i\0n\0/\0\x63\0o\0\x64\0i\0g\0o\0 \0\x64\0\x65\0 \0\x62\0\x61\0r\0r\0\x61\0.\0p\0n\0g
```

like the imgage
[I dont know what is this code, of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeOev.png)

Comment: Hello Gustavo, and welcome to StackOverflow!
Can you, please, improve your question adding details about what are you trying to do (what images are you trying to replace? Did you write the APK yourself or is a third party package?), what software are you using and possibly a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm not an expert in Android development, but you'll easily find some with a clearer title and a more specific question!

Comment: Hello Andrea, thanks for help me, I'll add the details